# What is the difference between these two syntax?

Tags: ruby

I am trying to do a script who checks .tar.gz files.
This is a part of the script :

```
  def tar
    tar_file =  %x( ls -t *.tar.gz | head -1)
    if tar_file.empty?
      critical "No tar.gz found"
    end
    tar_file.chomp
    command = "gunzip -c backup.tar.gz | tar t > /dev/null"
    system(command)
  end
```

This is working fine, but I don't know my backup name so I need to replace it by a variable. In this case, it's my variable `tar_file`.
So it gives me :

```
command = "gunzip -c #{tar_file} | tar t > /dev/null"
```

But when I execute this, I have the output of the `tar` command, it doesn't do the reddirection to /dev/null.

Do you know why it does it ?

Comment: Does the file contain spaces? String looks good to me when I try. Wrap the `#{tar_file}` in single quotes or escaped double quotes.

Comment: No it's doesn't, the file name is backup.tar.gz. And single or escaped double quotes doesn't work.

Comment: When you output the `command` value, what do you see?

Comment: I see  : gunzip -c backup.tar.gz
 | tar t > /dev/null but this is weird , the \n shouldn't be here, i took it away with .chomp method ... EDIT : Actually there is a /n between backup.tar.gz and the pipe, but don't know how to do a /n in stackoverflow comments ...

Comment: Very odd. Should work.

Comment: "i took it with .chomp method" – yes, but you throw away the result.

Comment: Do you see only errors? Or all output? Try changing `>` to `&>` which will send all output, including errors, to `/dev/null`

Comment: That's ok I found out, thanks ! I did tar_file = tar_file.chomp and now it works fine.

Comment: @JörgWMittag ahh you're right... Missed that part. OP, you can use `chomp!` instead, which directly writes to the object without having to reassign it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a `\n` at the end of `tar_file`, so I just called the method `tar_file.chomp!` to remove it.